# How to delete one duplicate row and keep the other in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table:

```
 |date|ticker|eps|
 |2020|AAPL|2.65|
 |2019|AAPL|1.44|
 |2019|GSKY|2.45|
 |2020|GOOGL|0.45|
 |2019|GOOGL|3.43|
```

Expected Output:
I want to delete a duplicate previous year ticker row but keep the recent year row (i.e 2020)

```
 |date|ticker|eps|
 |2020|AAPL|2.65|
 |2019|GSKY|2.45|
 |2020|GOOGL|0.45|
```

Comment: Hint: `ROW_NUMBER()`. There's a lot of similar questions on SO

Comment: Why not `delete <table> where [date] < 2020`? Oh - you want to keep the "last" one. NVM

Comment: @SMor Nope, that will delete `2019|GSKY` too.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [ticker],MAX([date]) as [date]
INTO [NEW_TABLE]
FROM [TABLE]
GROUP BY [ticker]
```